# Are there advantages to EFI for Linux guest in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux, efi

I want to install guest Linux (Arch Linux to be exact) through Virtualbox. Virtualbox has optional EFI support, I'm wondering if enabling it provides any pros for linux guests or not.

Comment: The only use for this I have found is that once Ubuntu broke the EFI system with an update, and I was able to reproduce the problem and confirm the fix on a VM.  Otherwise it hasn't made much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, when I last tested it, booting an EFI-mode Linux using VirtualBox was a few seconds quicker. EFI-mode booting also provides different native video modes, but those are only accessible for text-mode use or if you use the "fbdev" X11 device driver. Beyond that, unless you're involved in EFI development or are interested in testing or learning about EFI-mode booting, it won't make much difference.